# Canada eTA eligibility requirements?

Tags: canada, h1b-visas, eta

I have applied for [eTA](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/news/2017/04/canada_s_new_entryrulesforbrazilianbulgarianandromaniancitizens.html) and my case was approved.

I'm on H4 and my H4 visa is active or valid until Sep 2020.  If I have to travel to Canada on eTA, can I enter the country with my H4 document or do I need to have a passport stamping of my H4 visa to enter Canada on eTA?

Thanks,

Comment: eTA is not a visa.

Comment: You say you have an H-4 visa valid until September 2020, and then you ask about "passport stamping of your H-4 visa."  This suggests that you actually do not have a valid H-4 visa, but only valid H-4 *status.*  Is that the case?

Comment: Also, which country are you asking about when you say "can I enter the country with my H4 document"?  And what H-4 document are you asking about there?

Comment: Also, are you a Brazilian, Bulgarian, or Romanian citizen?

Answer (score 2):

Canada normally won't care too much about your H-4 visa, though they might care about it if they think you'll have trouble getting back to the US when you leave Canada.  Your question suggests there may be some confusion about whether you have a valid H-4 *visa* or H-4 *status.*  This answer assumes that your H-4 visa is expired, and that you have valid H-4 status until September 2020, which should be reflected on your I-94.

If you go to Canada for 30 days or less, you can be readmitted to the US without a valid H-4 visa under *automatic visa revalidation.*  The US government has pages describing this at the websites of both the [state department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date/auto-revalidate.html) and [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors).  There are some restrictions, including that you may not have a pending visa application.

If your trip to Canada is longer than 30 days, you will need a new visa in  your passport.  You should be able to get that while you're in Canada.  I don't know whether Canadian border officers are going to like that, but as far as I understand it, traveling to Canada for the purpose of visiting a US consulate to get a new visa is fairly common, so you should presumably have a fairly good chance of being admitted.

Because one of the conditions of automatic visa revalidation is that you not have a pending visa application, if you go to Canada and apply for a new H-4 visa, you will not be able to return to the US until it is granted and placed in your passport.